# Count entries with grid

Tags: grid, count

is it possible to total count grid from many entries?

Lets say, i have 3 channel entries. Channel 1 entry 1 has 3 grid entries, channel 1 entry 2 has 5 grid entries, channel 1 entry 3 has 7 grid entries.

The result should be 15. Also show beside the grid entries the number 1, 2, 3, ... 15

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This can be done a couple of ways.
1 - manually! enable PHP in the template and doing it that way.

2 - addon, i have used one before that i cannot quite track down now... but something like TALLY should do the job, try playing over at devot-ee:
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/tally

I might have even created a simple plugin myself to do this in the past. I truely cannot remember. But there is certainly options out there on devot-ee.

Answer (score 1):

In 2.7.3 there are variables within grid, see http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/grid.html#variables

```
{fieldname:count} //the current row being displayed
{fieldname:field_row_count} //how many rows are in the grid
{fieldname:total_rows} //the rows being returned by the query
```

Comment: Ah, gotcha, apologies I didn't read the question properly.